# React - Problems with function parameters for assigning values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I have a sidebar where it is possible to change the background of the sidebar as a background, I store pictures in the object, everything worked well for me until I decided to add a second property "`color`" inside the object, that is, in addition to changing the background, the color of the text also changes. it looks like this

[image]

I think that the essence is clear, but as I mentioned earlier, the problems started when I decided to add a second property, that is, the color of the text

The problem is that the `color` property does not work for me, that is, it works, but in this case the sidebar background does not work

My object looks very simple

```
import Bg from "../../SideBar/Background/mac.jpg"
import Pink from "../../SideBar/Background/pink.jpg"
import Anapa from "../../SideBar/Background/anapa.jpg"

const SideBarBackgrounds = [
    {
        SideBarWallpaper: Bg,
        color: "red",
    },
    {
        SideBarWallpaper: Pink,
        color: "green",
    },
    {
        SideBarWallpaper: Anapa,
        color: "yellow",
    },
].map((item) => {
        return {
            SideBarWallpaper: item.SideBarWallpaper,
            color: item.color,
        }
    }
)
```

export default SideBarBackgrounds;

That is, I import the picture and apply it as the value for the SideBarWallpaper properties then create a second property named `color` and apply the string as the color

Then I use local storage to save the user changes.

```
export const CounterContext = createContext([]);

export default function ThemeDoc(props) {

    const [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("BgKey")));

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("BgKey", JSON.stringify(SideBarBackground));
    })

    const ChangeSideBarWallpaper = (SideBarWallpaper) => {
        localStorage.setItem('BgKey', JSON.stringify(SideBarWallpaper));
        SetSideBarBackground(SideBarWallpaper);
    }

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{
                SideBarWallpaperValue: [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground],
            }}>
                <SideBar ChangeSideBarWallpaper={ChangeSideBarWallpaper} SideBarPageContent={SideBarPageContent} {...props} />
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, I use React Context since I have a lot of themes and I import them in many files, in this case I deleted everything personal and left only the code that belongs to the background of the sidebar

Then I have a component called `SideBarWallpaperContainer` where I import my object, create a loop using a map, process each property from the object and finally import the `SideBarWallpaperContainer` component inside the `SideBarModal` component

```
export default function SideBarWallpaperContainer(props) {

    const SideBarWallpaperList = SideBarBackgrounds.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <img key={index} width={"70"} height={"55"} src={theme.SideBarWallpaper}
                 className={"SideBar_Appearance_Select_Icon"}
                 onClick={() => props.ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme.SideBarWallpaper)} alt={"Select Theme"}/>
        );
    })
    return (
        <>
            {SideBarWallpaperList}
        </>
    );
}
```

**SideBarModal.jsx**

```
const DraggableDialog = (props) => {
   ...
   return(
      <SideBarWallpaperContainer {...props} />
      ...
  );
}
```

Through props, I get the `ChangeSideBarWallpaper` method to change the background and color

And the color for the sidebar text I get using `useContext` it looks like this

**SideBarMenu.jsx**

```
export default function SideBarMenu(props) {

    const {SideBarWallpaperValue} = React.useContext(CounterContext);

    const [SideBarWallpaperTheme,] = SideBarWallpaperValue;
    const SideBarWallpaperStyle = SideBarWallpaperTheme;

return(

        <Link
           style={{ color: SideBarWallpaperStyle && SideBarWallpaperStyle.color,}}>{item.name}
        </Link>

);

}
```

Now when you roughly understand how all the logic works, I want to explain the problem. The problem is that either the sidebar color or the background does not work for me, please pay attention to the method

```
props.ChangeSideBarWallpaper (theme.SideBarWallpaper)}
```

When I use `theme.SideBarWallpaper` as a parameter inside the `ChangeSideBarWallpaper` method, only the background works for me and not the color, and this is of course logical, then I tried to apply 2 parameters, the color and the background, it looked like this

```
onClick={() => props.ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme.SideBarWallpaper, theme.color)}
```

But in this case, only the background also worked and the only solution that remained for me to transfer the entire value, it looked like this

```
onClick={() => props.ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme)}
```

And then I was surprised now only the sidebar color works for me but the background does not work, You can look at the picture (sorry if I'm so long and boring to explain :) I just want you to understand the problem as clearly as possible)

[image]

I decided to check if I get a picture and yes I get

[image]

[image]

Now that you understand the problem, I will be interested in hearing your advice, thank you for paying attention to my long question.

Answer (score 0):

Before I demonstrate the solution, I would like to say that the problem lies with me, I, as always, introduced myself impatiently and inattentively: (it turns out that I forgot that in the `SideBar` component I get the `SideBarBackground` value in short, the code looked like this

```
    const {someValue} = useContext(SideBarContext);
    const {SideBarValue, SideBarWallpaperValue} = React.useContext(CounterContext);

    const [SideBarTheme] = SideBarValue;
    const [SideBarBackground] = SideBarWallpaperValue;

<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${SideBarBackground})`}}>
...
</div>
```

Then I got the `SideBarWallpaper` value

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${SideBarBackground.SideBarWallpaper})`}}>
...
</div>
```